# Syntax error in string in query expression 'ID = 4

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, vbe

I am using Visual Basic 2010 express to control a Ms.Access 2007 database. I am struggling in adding a record to the database.

I get the Syntax error in string in query expression 'ID = 4

Here is my code :

```
 If ComboBox1.Text = "" Or TxtJam.Text = "" Or TxtAudio.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data belum lengkap", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, messageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else

            myqry = "UPDATE TblJadwal SET "
            myqry = myqry + " Hari = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "',"
            myqry = myqry + " Jam = '" & TxtJam.Text & "',"
            myqry = myqry + " Audio = '" & TxtAudio.Text & "'"
            myqry = myqry + "WHERE "

            myqry = myqry + "ID = " & TxtID.Text & "'"
            mycmd = New OleDbCommand(myqry, conn)
            mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Call Set1()
        End If
```

and my database

```
ID , autonumber
Hari, text 
Jadwal, text 
Jam, Text
```

Comment: Have you some particular reason for using an unbound form? You are losing half the reason for using MS Access in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem:

```
"ID = " & TxtID.Text & "'"
```

You are adding a `'` at the end. Incorrect syntax.

You should either have one at the start as well, or non at all (if ID is numeric).

```
"ID = '" & TxtID.Text & "'"
```

Or:

```
"ID = " & TxtID.Text
```